# Flag and input field issue for intl-tel-input CSS

Tags: css, intl-tel-input

I am trying to integrate a intl-tel-input fied in a form, using a specific template.
I cannot solve the issue of having the flag overlapping the input field.
I also would like to set the dropdown list to an inversed color(black background and white letters) to match the visual of the page.

```
 <div class="  input-group">
  <input  class="form-control" type="text" type="tel" id="mobile_code"  name="name">
</div>
```

[image: form issue]

i have attached my code in this [codepen](https://codepen.io/rdugert/pen/wvjXEBX)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to css. Css from library sets wrong values.

```
.iti--allow-dropdown .iti__flag-container, .iti--separate-dial-code .iti__flag-container {
  right:0;
  left:auto;
}
```

Comment: this nearly works, it puts the drop down on the right of the box, the preferred option would be left

Answer (score 0):

just add the following

```css
.iti--allow-dropdown input{
    padding-left: 52px;}
```

css